# Xamarin android display image from external Storage

Tags: android, image, xamarin, android-external-storage

I'm currently trying to displa an image from the storage, but I have no success.

What I'm dooing.

```
  public Stream ReadImage(string path) 
    {

        //var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
        //var stream = MainActivity._activity.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);
        //return stream;
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var source = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            source.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }

        return memoryStream;
    }
```

string path = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190521_094202.jpg"

```
     var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(
            delegate { 
                return DependencyService.Get<IMediaHelper>().ReadImage(path);
            });
```

But in the using line the programm doese not proceed, it does not reach the following lines and it does not load the file from the storage, the way with the contetn resolver does end teh same way, in the contentresolver line.

I have the Read/write external storage permission.

I am using android x, with Xamarin 5.0.0.2012. Under android 10 & and 11, on multiple different xiaomi devices.

This might be a bug, because I think, I had it running in an earlier project.

Some insight woult be appreciated, I'm biting my teath out on this nut.

Comment: why not use `ImageSource.FromFile(path)`?

Comment: I have tried that, works equaly bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give users more control over their files and to limit file clutter, apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage, by default. Such apps have access only to the app-specific directory on external storage, as well as specific types of media that the app has created.You could read it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).

For android 10,you could request the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` attribute in your `Application` tag in the `AndroidManifest`.

```
<application android:label="NewForms.Android" android:resizeableActivity="true" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
```

For android 11,you need add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your `AndroidManifest`.And determine in the Activity whether the permission is enabled.

And you can't forget to dynamically request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions (this was added after Android 6.0,named [Runtime Permissions](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/runtime_perms)).

The final code is as follows：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.newforms" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
<application android:label="NewForms.Android" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>   
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

and you could request the [runtime permission like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows#runtime-permission-checks-in-android-60) in your MainActivity:

```
RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage}, 0);
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.Q)
      {
          if (!Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
          {
             StartActivityForResult(new Intent( Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAllFilesAccessPermission), 101);
          }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, but I realy dont understand why Google would do this? Why replace an old permission with a new one , no ordenary user in the world will recognize the difference.